# Use Windows VPN connection to Azure P2S VPN from MacOS

Tags: windows, azure, routes, parallels, azure-vpn

Scenario:

- Windows 10 Virtual Machine hosted using Parallels on MacOS Catalina
- Azure VPN - Basic SKU
- Shared Network setup using Parallels

I can successfully connect to the Azure VPN using a Point-to-site connection from the Windows 10 installation.

**Problem: I would like to use the VPN connection (established by Windows 10 VM) with macOS Host. Is this possible?**

I have tried adding a static route on Mac OS as below, where 10.200.0.0/16 is the Azure Network CIDR, and 10.211.55.6 is the IP address of the Windows 10 VM on Parallels.

```sh
sudo route add -net 10.200.0.0/16 10.211.55.6
```

But this does not work. Any suggestions, or is there no way to share the VPN connection even with custom routing configuration?

> Note. I understand that you can connect to Azure VPN from MacOS using the Standard SKU of Azure VPN, but would like to see if it is possible without.